# When migrating from ListView to Flatlist I am getting values in object I need to get as a value

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When migrating from ListView to Flatlist I am getting values in an object I need to get as a value in array.

I have modified the react-native-modal-filter-picker to a custom component which needs to work for me. Here onSelect shows the results in object.

```
renderOptionList = () => {
   const {
     noResultsText,
     listViewProps,
     keyboardShouldPersistTaps,
     keyExtractor,
   } = this.props

   const { ds } = this.state;
   if (!ds.length) {
     return (
     <FlatList
       data={ds}
         keyExtractor={keyExtractor||this.keyExtractor}
         {...listViewProps}
         renderItem={() => (
           <View style={styles.noResults}>
             <Text style={styles.noResultsText}>{noResultsText}</Text>
           </View>
         )}
       />
     )
   } else {
     return (
       <FlatList
         keyExtractor={keyExtractor||this.keyExtractor}
         {...listViewProps}
         data={ds}
         renderItem={this.renderOption}
       />
     )
   }
 };

 renderOption = ({item}) => {
   const {
     selectedOption,
     renderOption,
     optionTextStyle,
     selectedOptionTextStyle
   } = this.props;

   const { key, label } = item
   let style = styles.optionStyle;
   let textStyle = optionTextStyle||styles.optionTextStyle;
   if (key === selectedOption) {
     style = styles.selectedOptionStyle;
     textStyle = selectedOptionTextStyle ||styles.selectedOptionTextStyle
   }

   if (renderOption) {
     return renderOption(item, key === selectedOption)
   } else {
     return (
       <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7}
         style={style}
         onPress={() => this.props.onSelect(item)}
       >
         <Text style={textStyle}>{label}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
```

Output will be

```
["somestring", 42, false]
```

Comment: In my above code the Flatlist renderOption Onselect returns object. How can I change that. Also I need only one value not all the value in onselect\

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
JSON.stringfy(object)
```

A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.

JSON.stringfy convert a JavaScript object into a string.

Comment: While this may be a correct/useful answer, consider including some additional context or a short explanation about _why_ this works.

Comment: @ZGski added an explanation in my answer. Thanks